# Worklight Direct update

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Does anybody know what if direct update updates everything that lives in the common directory structure.  I used the same code base for multiple apps, the only change being certain settings within a js file that tells the application how to act. Is there a directory i can put that js file that would be safe from the direct update feature?

I cant seen to find any specific information on IBM's website.

Comment: Normally, you should put environment specific js code in the apps/app_name/environment_name/js/app_name.js file. You use the wlEnvInit() function to do your specific settings. But, why are you worried about the code in the js file? When the app updates it only changes the files that were changed. Is there a reason why you are afraid of that code changing?

Comment: The problem im having is that i have one app that can connection to one of multiple stores in the backend.  So all i do is change the config.js and it will decided which store this app represents.  So technicall to worklight it looks like 1 app, but depending on the config i package with it, it technically be a diffent store app. My worry is that since worklight sees it as 1 app it will update everything including the config.js and that will technically change the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge Direct Update will update every web resource of the skin you're using (html, css, js). However, I'm no expert with it.

If you're supporting only Android and iOS applications and need a way to store settings I recommend JSONStore. Otherwise look into [Cordova Storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage), [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) or [IndexedDB](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-indexeddb/index.html?ca=drs-).

Using a JSONStore collection called `settings` will allow you to store data on disk inside the app's directory. It will persist until you call one of the removal methods like [destroy](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_destroy.html) or until the application is uninstalled. There are also ways of linking collections to Worklight Adapters to pull/push data from/to a server. The links below will provide further details.

> the only change being certain settings within a js

Create a collection for your settings:

```
var options = {};
options.onSuccess = function () {
    //... what to do after init finished
};
options.onFailure = function () {
    //... what to do if init fails
}
var settings = WL.JSONStore.initCollection('settings',
    {background: 'string', itemsPerPage: 'number'}, options);
```

You can add new settings after initCollection onSuccess has been called:

```
settings.add({background: 'red', itemsPerPage: 20}, options);
```

You can find settings stored after initCollection onSuccess has been called:

```
settings.findAll({onSuccess: function (results) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
}});
```

You can read more about JSONStore in the [Getting Started Modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#mobile-client-development). See Modules: 7.9, 7.10, 7.11, 7.12. There is further information inside the API Documentation in [IBM InfoCenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_class_wl_jsonstore.html). The methods described above are: [initCollection](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_initcollection.html), [add](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_add.html) and [findAll](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_findall.html).

Comment: So can i load the configs i have in my js file. then not worry when the app gets updated.  because if you look at above, i have 1 app that represents 5 stores, so depending on the config.js i package with the app it connections to a different stores, and shows different logo's

Answer (score 3):

I think you guys need to be careful which terms you are using in order to not confuse people who may be looking for similar help.

**Environments** are specific to the OS you are using. iOS, Blackberry, Android, and etc. environments.

Skins are based on the environment, and aren't generic to all platform. When you create a skin you must choose which environment you are running in.

So to correct some, direct updates will update **all** skin resources in targeted environments.

For example: You have an app with Android and iOS versions

When you create skins, you are creating essentially a responsive type of design to your parameters. For instance, if you have a 2.3 vs 4.2 Android OS, you can set a look and feel for both. However, these utilize a single web resource base. The APK would be the same for both versions of the app (by default) and have 2 available skins. On **runtime** utilizing IBM Worklight's **'Runtime Skinning'** (hence the name) it goes through the parameter check for the OS and loads that skins overriding web code.

You could technically override all of the web code to be completely different for both skins, but that would be bulky and inefficient.

When you direct update you are updating all the resources of that particular **environment** (to include both skins), not the common folder/environment.

So an updated Android (both skins) would have updated web resources (if you deployed the android wlapp) and an iOS version would stay the same.

If you look at the Android project after build (native -> assets -> www -> default or skin) you can find the shared web resources generated by the common environment. However that is only put there every time you do a new build.

[image: Browser Test]
In the picture, I have an older version of the Android built for both skins on the left. On the right is a preview of the newer **common** resources after deploying only the **common.wlapp**. So you can see that they are separate.

Sorry if it was long winded, but I thought I would be thorough.

**To answer the original question**, have you thought of having all the parameters of the store loaded from user input or a setup? If you are trying to connect to 3 different store, create some form for settings control that will access different back ends or specific adapters. You could also create 3 different config.js that load depending on the parameters that you set so that you set. The other option is to set different versions of your apps specific to the store.

Example. Version 1.11, 1.12,1.13 can be 3 versions of the same app for store 1, 2, & 3. They can be modified and change and have 3 sets of web resources. When you need to update, jump up to version 1.21, 1.22,1.23. It seems a bit of a work around, but it may be your best bet at getting 3 versions of the same app to fall within the single application category. (keep 3 config.js types for modifying for the 3 stores).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  The client does not want the customer to know what the store relationships are, so they want the apps branded.  But the version trick seems like a good one.  In the end it looks like we are probably going to either load the config into the json store on first run, or convince the client to get more licenses depending on cost.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 5.0.3 I think, direct update will not update all the webresources, only those of the skin you are using.

say you have skin def and skin skin2
you are on def

1. make change to def on the server -> you will get a direct update for
   def only
2. make change to skin2 on server-> no direct update for you.

you are on skin2:

1. make change to skin2 on server -> direct update for skin2 only
2. - make change to def javascript which also resides on skin2 ( and therefor end result is def+skin2 concatination), update only skin2
   - make change to def,just to a picture(also checking pic extension from application-descriptor: ") -> no direct update

Thats how direct update works.

Please also share some more details about what is the problem, I see you use a js file, where do you change it? what do you mean excatly, give a better (simplified) real life example, because it is unclear what you are trying.

Comment: I have 1 code base,  The config.js file specifies what backend(store) and what logos to use.  So company A owns stores 1, 2 and 3.  The app code is the same except for the config.js which tells the app what Store(either 1,2 or 3) its supposed to represent.  So the config Js holds information like Options.StoreId, Options.StoreName, Options.StoreLogo.  Also part of the reason for this is the customer has the consumer edition and is playing for 1 app. So i would like to keep the Config.js out of direct updates path.